# How can i prove $p\to (q \vee r) \equiv (p \wedge \sim q) \to r$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

please Help me in this question

i have tried to solve it like this:

$$p \to (q \vee r) \equiv (p \wedge \sim q)\to r$$
$$p \vee \sim (q \vee r) \equiv \sim(p \wedge q)\vee r$$
$$p \vee \sim q \wedge \sim r \equiv \sim p \vee q \vee r$$
Thank you

Comment: Your first step is wrong : $p \to (q \lor r)$ is equivalent to $\lnot p \lor (q \lor r)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the rule of implication we have
$$p\to (q\vee r) \equiv \sim p \vee (q \vee r).$$
Using associativity we have 
$$\sim p \vee (q \vee r) \equiv (\sim p \vee q) \vee r.$$
Next is De Morgan
$$(\sim p \vee q) \vee r \equiv \sim(p \wedge \sim q) \vee r .$$
And now use implication once again
$$\sim(p \wedge \sim q) \vee r \equiv (p \wedge \sim q) \to r .$$

Regarding you answer:

Your first step is what you need to prove. What is the second step?

**Edit**

The rule of implication is
$$ a\to b \equiv \sim a\vee b.$$

Comment: thanks Ludolila ..but are we need to associativity again in the end ??

Comment: Do you mean the last step? We don't need associativity there, just implication. Why do you think we do?

Comment: sorry i was not sure .. you helped me i was lost thanks